# YouTube thinks my web server's IP is in the Philippines?

Tags: php, youtube, webserver, hosting, region

I'm experiencing an issue that causes YouTube to load in Filipino rather than English. Everything has been working fine for the past 6 months up until today. My web server is hosted in the US and all the IP addresses point to Texas. I'm loading a YouTube page with PHP on this site: http://getlikes.us/testget.php

```
$youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8To-6VIJZRE";
$data = file_get_contents($youtubeURL);
echo $data;
```

Which results in the page loading in Filipino:

[image]

I'm unsure where to go from here. What is causing YouTube to think the region is the Philippines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it is doing that, maybe their algorithm has a glitch or your server is sending something strange.  That server is in TX, US and the IPs are registered to a TX, US block.

You might need to send an `Accept-Language` header with `stream_context_create()` and use the stream context in `file_get_contents()`:

```
$opts = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET",
                            'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
                           )
             );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8To-6VIJZRE";
$data = file_get_contents($youtubeURL, false, $context);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Thank you for this easy workaround. The page now loads in English. YouTube is still suggesting that I switch Filipino, but for my purposes that is of no concern. Very strange indeed.